# Collapsible CSHTML files and resources

Tags: visual-studio-2010, razor

Razor view files normally don't have collapsible state unless we manually add some dependant files by editing CSPROJ files directly.

This works great for other content files like javascript files as shown on my image. I just had to manually add `DependentUpon` XML element in CSPROJ file to display underneath.

[image: Collapsible CSHTML]

**The problem that I would like to solve** is how to also add resource file under my CSHTML view file? Resources are not listed as content in CSPROJ of course because they're embedded resources...

The best way would of course be for Visual Studio to do this automatically when we add an additional file and the whole name equals some other file's name with extension, it should just put it underneath. But VS doesn't do this automatically so...

### Is this possible? Natively? Using a VS addin maybe?